# Prove the convexity for f: $\mathbb{R}^3$ $\to$ $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-geometry

The problem below is one of my homework for the Convex Geometry course. 
I have tried to prove by using the Hessian matrix or the gradient but cannot figure out the right answers.

> Show that
>   $$
> f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = \cfrac1{x_1-\cfrac{1}{x_2-\cfrac1{x_3}}}
> $$
>   is convex on $\left(\Bbb R_*^+\right)^3$.

Can you help me on this, please?

Comment: Did you manage to compute the Hessian matrix in the first place?

Comment: I tried to but it seems to complicated.

Comment: I tried too, and you're right, [it's rather ugly](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Hessian+of+1%2F%28x-%281%2F%28y-1%2Fz%29%29%29). I wouldn't particularily fancy showing that it's positive semidefinite. Let's hope someone can find a cleverer way.

Comment: Yeah. Hence I think there must be some other ways, such as using test or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is not convex. Set $\alpha = 1/2$. Then

\begin{align}
0.75 =f(2,2,2) &= f(\alpha(1,1,1) + (1-\alpha)(3,3,3)) \\
&> \alpha f(1,1,1) + (1-\alpha)f(3,3,3) = \alpha 0 + (1-\alpha)\frac{15}{56} \\
&\approx 0.134
\end{align}

which violates the [convexity inequality.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Definition) You can see this from just looking at [the subset of $f$'s graph where $x_1=x_2=x_3$.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/87w6qqyulg)